# Есть ли способ снифать трафик приложений НЕ через прокси?

Tags: android, мобильная-разработка, мобильные-приложения, сниффер

Никакие Шарки, Фидлеры, Чарльзы и Брупсайты не берут например такие приложения как vk и instagram.
Все упирается в прокси тунель, и не важно есть сертфикат или нет.

Запросы отправляются, ответы не получаются :(

Есть ли какой-то иной способ снифать трафик мобильных приложений?

Answer (score 1):

Вывод  SSLKEYLOG стандартными средствами не нахожу, но вот есть интересный проект https://github.com/saleemrashid/frida-sslkeylog заявленно что можно разобрать трафик у динамически собранных приложений